# How to override @GeneratedValue declared in mapped-superclass?

Tags: hibernate, orm

We have a `@MappedSuperclass class Entity` which defines the default id and the generator:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Override
public K getId() {
    return id;
}
```

I want to not use any generator in subclass `Foo` at all, because I will provide the primary key myself.

I must extend `Foo` from the base class `Entity`, because a lot and a lot functions depend on this base class. The annotation `@AttributeOverrides` seems not support to override `@GeneratedValue`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I override the GenerationType strategy using Hibernate/JPA annotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328202/how-do-i-override-the-generationtype-strategy-using-hibernate-jpa-annotations)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like `Foo` is not actually a subtype of `Entity` and should never have really extended it.  Inheritance is a strong contract.  You would not extend a something just to get access to some methods.

In hibernate when you get a Foo object from the database you are actually also selecting from the Entity table.  Both tables are joined via their `@Id` field, you will see the the `Id` in the `Foo` will be the same as the `Id` in `Entity`.

This enables us to do the following.

```
Entity entity = new Foo();
if (entity instanceof Foo) {
  //we have a Foo object
} else if( entity instanceof ...) {
  //we have a ...
}
```

If you want to supply your own Id you should no longer extend the super class.  If you have a whole lot of logic you want to include into a number of hibernate classes but they are not really subtypes of the class, consider using `@Embedded` instead.

Comment: I think Xie has mentioned that his base class is a mapped superclass and not an entity so his mappedsuperclass will not be mapped to a table and so the issue of join would not arrive. Using abstract methods for id in base class and annotating the getter methods in derived class seems to be the way.