# How to extends a superclass to have common getters/setters with Hibernate reverse engineer

Tags: java, hibernate

I am generating java classes from a database (using Hiberndate reverse engineering). All of my generated class will have something like this (just to make sure, uid_xxxxx is the primary key from the DB table):

```
private Integer uidCompany;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "uid_company", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getUidCompany() {
  return this.uidCompany;
}

public void setUidCompany(Integer uidCompany) {
this.uidCompany = uidCompany;
}
```

so I wrote this class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class HibernateObject implements Serializable {
   protected Integer uniqueID;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
   public Integer getUniqueID() {
   return this.uniqueID;
   }

   public void setUniqueID(Integer aUID) {
   this.uniqueID = aUID;
   }
}
```

I would like all the classes generated from hibernate reverse engineering to extends it. As you can probably guess, I also want the "uid_xxxxx" attribute to not be created and instead save the value into the parent's attribute "uniqueID". I could do it manually, but I often find myself having to regenerate my classes, which is why I want the reverse-engineer process to do it.

I looked around a little bit, and found these links to be usefull, but I guess I'm still missing something. Any help would be appreciated!

http://ocpsoft.org/java/hibernate-use-a-base-class-to-map-common-fields/

http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/hibernate/

[How do I override the GenerationType strategy using Hibernate/JPA annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328202/how-do-i-override-the-generationtype-strategy-using-hibernate-jpa-annotations)

```
/******************************************EDIT******************************/
```

So here's what I ended up with after reading your suggestion:

Okay, so I followed your instruction and here is what I ended up with:

```
public abstract class HibernateObject implements Serializable {
public abstract Integer getUniqueID();  
public abstract void setUniqueID(Integer aUID);
}
```

and

```
public class MyReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {
public MyReverseEngineeringStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy aDelegate) {
super(aDelegate);
}

@Override
public String columnToPropertyName(TableIdentifier table, String column) {
 if(column.startsWith("uid_")) {
  return "uniqueID";
 }
 else {
  return super.columnToPropertyName(table, column);
 }
}

@Override
public Map<String, MetaAttribute> tableToMetaAttributes(TableIdentifier tableIdentifier) {
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 Map<String, MetaAttribute> metaAttributes = super.tableToMetaAttributes(tableIdentifier);

  if(metaAttributes == null) {
   metaAttributes = new HashMap<String, MetaAttribute>();
  }

  // All generated classes will extend utils.HibernateObject class
  MetaAttribute extendsAttribute = new MetaAttribute("extends");
  extendsAttribute.addValue("utils.HibernateObject");
  metaAttributes.put("extends", extendsAttribute);

  return metaAttributes;
  }
}
```

Now all my hibernate method extends HibernateObject, and since the parameter for the id is named "uniqueID", the getters and setters created by the code generator overrides the required functions.

I still have a (minor) problem though: when I use HQL query language like this:
    List picklist = session.createQuery("FROM Picklist").list();

I get an error like this : "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unknown column 'picklist0_.uniqueID' in 'field list'"

I know I get this error because there is no such field in my DataBase table, and I think it happens because hibernate try to get the field name from the attributes name it generated. However there is no such method as "PropertyNameToColumn" in DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy to do the reverse name transformation. Any idea what I missed? Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class for Reverse Engineering strategy which extends any of the defined strategies like 'DelegateRevereseEngineeringStrategy' or 'DefaultReverseEngineeringStrategy'. Then, override the provided methods

1. To exclude the column, override the following method

   ```
   public boolean excludeColumn(TableIdentifier identifier, String columnName) {
     if(columnName.startsWith("uid_")) {
        return true;
     }
     return delegate==null?false:delegate.excludeColumn(identifier, columnName);
   }
   ```
2. To extends the generated classes from a base class, add the meta attributes using method

   ```
   public Map<String, MetaAttribute> tableToMetaAttributes(TableIdentifier tableIdentifier) {

     Map<String, MetaAttribute> metaAttributes = super.tableToMetaAttributes(tableIdentifier);

     if(metaAttributes == null) {
       metaAttributes = new HashMap<String, MetaAttribute>();
     }
     // All generated classes will extend com.abc.Test class
     MetaAttribute extendsAttribute = new MetaAttribute("extends");
     extendsAttribute.addValue("com.abc.Test");
     metaAttributes.put("extends", extendsAttribute);
     return metaAttributes;
   }
   ```

You can also do these using the reveng.xml file. For more tips , refer to this [post](http://allzhere.in/2013/04/22/hibernate-reverse-engineering-tips/)

Comment: Okay, so I followed your instruction and here is what I ended up with:


    public abstract class HibernateObject implements Serializable {
    public abstract Integer getUniqueID(); 
    public abstract void setUniqueID(Integer aUID);}

Comment: Sorry for the last comment, I'm not to familiar with the way stackoverflow's commenting/posting works, see the edit for the actual comment